# Probabability Paradox

Tags: conditional-probability

Suppose you have $6$ fair weighted dice with all faces having $1$ to $6$. since the outcome is mutually independent and are disjointed sets, the probability of getting at least one six is $P(a)=6\cdot(1/6)$ by law of addition but if now there are $7$ dices so $P(a)$ is $7\cdot(1/6)$,how?

Now a follow up question -what is the probability of $6$ dices having Same sides except $6$ which is $P(b)=5(\frac16)^6$

But we know $P(a)$, probabability of getting at least $1$ six in $6$ dice is $1$, so this means $P(b)=0$ since one side must have six but earlier we exclude it.

Comment: I think you're confusing the probability of getting at least one six, with the expected number of sixes. No matter how many dice you roll, there is a nonzero probability of not rolling any sixes.

Answer (score 4):

The probability of having at least one 6 is $1-(\tfrac{5}{6})^6$.

The events are not disjoint: you can have 6 in dice #1 and in dice #2 at the same time.